# How to empty a toggled text box that has focus on a change of check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this https://jsfiddle.net/5ep34nj8/5/ and the toggle feature works great.

Aside, I'd like to empty the toggled text box when check box isn't checked. I've searched for about an hour now without any result.

I tried to take out the focus on the text box, and it doesn't change a thing. Text box won't empty itself as it is now.

```js
function toggleOtherLanguagesTextBox() {
  var effect = 'slide';
  $("#otherLanguagesPartial").toggle(effect, 0);
}

$("#otherLanguagesPartial").toggle(false);
$("#other").click(function() {
  toggleOtherLanguagesTextBox();

  if (!$("#other").is(":checked")) {
    $("#otherLanguages").focus(false);
    $("#otherLanguagesPartial").val("");
  }

  if ($("#other").is(":checked"))
    $("#otherLanguages").focus();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="languages[]" value="Other" />
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <div id="otherLanguagesPartial">
    <label for="otherLanguages">Please Specify:</label>
    <input type="text" id="otherLanguages" name="languages[]">
  </div>
</body>

<footer>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: `$("#otherLanguagesPartial").val("");` should be `$("#otherLanguages").val("");`

Comment: Also note that the `footer` element needs to be placed inside the `body`

Comment: Thanks for the edit @RoryMcCrossan, I wasn't aware of that way of inserting snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are trying to empty the `div` instead of `input`. So use `$("#otherLanguages").val("");` instead of `$("#otherLanguagesPartial").val("");` in your click method.

See the Snippet below:

```js
function toggleOtherLanguagesTextBox() {
  var effect = 'slide';
  $("#otherLanguagesPartial").toggle(effect, 0);
}

$("#otherLanguagesPartial").toggle(false);
$("#other").click(function() {
  toggleOtherLanguagesTextBox();

  if (!$("#other").is(":checked")) {
    $("#otherLanguages").focus(false);
    $("#otherLanguages").val("");
  }

  if ($("#other").is(":checked"))
    $("#otherLanguages").focus();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="languages[]" value="Other" />
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <div id="otherLanguagesPartial">
    <label for="otherLanguages">Please Specify:</label>
    <input type="text" id="otherLanguages" name="languages[]">
  </div>
</body>

<footer>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't get why I didn't see it, but front-end dev to me is like Chinese... Anyway, thanks for this answer. It helps. :)